Opening file upload in javascript
I have the following code that opens file upload in javascript. Is there another way to accomplish the same thing with another code?
<div>
      <input
          id="test-id"
          type="file"
          accept="jpg"
          @change=${async (e: Event) => {
             await this.handleImages(e.target as HTMLInputElement, roles);
          }}
      />
      <label for="test-id">Test</label>
</div>


@change is not standard HTML, and JS doesn't have type hinting, so which framework are you using, and remember to tag your post with that?  Also, probably more importantly, what do you actually need help with? Because if the code you're showing works, there is no problem that needs help, and if it doesn't work, explain what's going wrong.

...it's also not clear why you're using async/await for an event handler...

As the html5 standard specification states in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#file-upload-state-(type=file) - there is only one input of type file for file uploading.
Also can check here - https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/input.file.html
